In AVR-GCC, I am trying to get an atmega328p to sleep and then wake on USART RX, but it locks up
My hardware is pretty straight forward. I have an ATMEGA328P hooked up with an LED on PB5, primarily to troubleshoot, and a wire that connects PD2 (INT0) to PD0 (RX), hoping to use INT0 to wake up the microcontroller.
Below is my AVR-GCC code:
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

// define baud-rate of my serial port
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR F_CPU/16/BAUD-1

volatile uint8_t userState = 0;

void USART_Init(uint16_t ubrr);
unsigned char USART_receive(void);
void USART_Transmit(uint8_t data);
void serial_write_str(char* StringPtr);
void goToSleep(void);

//external interrupt 0 wakes the MCU
ISR(INT0_vect) {
    EIMSK = 0;                     //disable external interrupts (only need one to wake up)
}

// function to initialize my USART port on the ATMEGA328P
void USART_Init(uint16_t ubrr) {
    // Set baud rate
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
    
    // Set frame format to 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
    
    // Enable receiver and transmitter with RX interrupt
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXCIE0) | (1<<RXEN0) | (1<<TXEN0);
    
    // Set frame format: 8data, 1 stop bit
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ00) | (1 << UCSZ01);
}

// function to transmit/TX stuff out of the ATMEGA328P and into my laptop
void USART_Transmit(uint8_t data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    
    // Put data into buffer, sends the data
    UDR0 = data;
}

// function to read a character, one at a time from the serial port
unsigned char USART_Receive(void) {
    // Wait until a data is available
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)));

    // Now USART has got data from host and is available is buffer
    return UDR0;
}

// function to transmit/write a whole null terminated string to serial port
void serial_write_str(char* str) {
    while(*str != 0x00) {
        USART_Transmit(*str);
        str++;
    }
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
    char c = 0;
    
    c = USART_Receive();
    
    // if the enter key (ASCII 13) is pressed...
    if(c == 13) {
        userState = 1;
    } else {
        userState = 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    DDRB |= (1 << 5);   // PB5 Output
    PORTB &= ~(1 << 5); // off
    
    USART_Init(MYUBRR); // initialize USART
    sei();
    
    char message1[] = "Booting v1.0\r\n";
    serial_write_str(message1);
    _delay_ms(20);
    
    while (1) {
        goToSleep();
        PORTB |= (1 << 5);  // on
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB &= ~(1 << 5); // off
        _delay_ms(500);
        if(userState == 1) {
            char message2[] = "\r\nYou Pressed Enter\r\n";
            serial_write_str(message2);
            _delay_ms(20);
            userState = 0;
        } else {
            
        }
    }
}

void goToSleep(void) {
    uint8_t adcsra = ADCSRA;       //save the ADC Control and Status Register A
    ADCSRA = 0;                    //disable the ADC
    EICRA = _BV(ISC01);            //configure INT0 to trigger on falling edge
    EIMSK = _BV(INT0);             //enable INT0
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    cli();                         //stop interrupts to ensure the BOD timed sequence executes as required
    sleep_enable();
    //disable brown-out detection while sleeping (20-25µA)
    uint8_t mcucr1 = MCUCR | _BV(BODS) | _BV(BODSE);
    uint8_t mcucr2 = mcucr1 & ~_BV(BODSE);
    MCUCR = mcucr1;
    MCUCR = mcucr2;
    //sleep_bod_disable();           //for AVR-GCC 4.3.3 and later, this is equivalent to the previous 4 lines of code
    sei();                         //ensure interrupts enabled so we can wake up again
    sleep_cpu();                   //go to sleep
    sleep_disable();               //wake up here
    ADCSRA = adcsra;               //restore ADCSRA
}

It appears that my code runs and if I press the Enter key (or any key, really) on my terminal, the microcontroller blinks the PB5 LED, but doesn't register the RX interrupt. That's fine, that's expected, as when the atmega328p comes out of sleep, it wasn't awake the moment before to invoke the RX interrupt. And, if I do that, it continues to loop, like expected.
However, if I press Enter and Enter again quick enough, the first "Enter" trips the interrupt to wake up the microcontroller. The second Enter is registered by the RX interrupt, and it sees that I pressed Enter, or ASCII character 13, which changes the userState variable to 1. So back in my main while loop, seeing the userState changed to 1, it outputs on the USART "You Pressed Enter", resets the userState back to 0 and then goes back to the top of the while loop. Then it goes to sleep... and never wakes up, even if I type in more stuff, which should trip the INT0 interrupt, but it doesn't. I can even physically move the wire on INT0 from high to low voltages and it still won't respond.
Why?
Thanks for anyone who figures it out. I know it's got to be something bone headed that I am doing and am just not seeing it.

I think you should review the data sheet in which sleep modes it is possible to wake up on which events and which clock source you are using.
For example, in all sleep modes except "Idle", the IO clocks are halted so it should not be possible to wake on INT0 falling edge, only on low level detect.
Even if it does wake up, by the time your external oscillator starts up, the UART byte is long gone. Or rather, it may depend on which clock source you are using and how the fuse bits are set up.
For example it may take 1 to 2 milliseconds before a crystal oscillates stably, and the fuse bits define how many hundreds or thousands of clock cycles to wait until using that clock. Enough to miss a few bytes at 9600 bps.
Also if you use the internal RC oscillator, it can be started extremely fast. The downside is, does it run at stable frequency or does it just run at some frequency before it stabilizes, and another thing is, the internal oscillator is factory calibrated to something like 10% within 8 MHz and it is sensitive to temperature and voltage, so the internal RC oscillator should not be used for any serious purpose such as UART anyway, at least not without user calibration for oscillator frequency or baud rate.
Then, it only works only once, because a character like 0x13, there are multiple falling edes. When you first set the interrupt pin to be falling edge sensitive and enable it, it will trigger on the next falling edge. However, as you simply disable further EXTI0 interrupts in the IRQ handler, it will clear the pending interrupt flag when it exits the IRQ handler. But, any subsequent falling edges are still detected and the INTF0 flag is set pending. So when you next time want to go to sleep mode, you configure the INT0 pin for falling edges again, and enable INT0 interrupts - and then the pending INT0 happens, disabling further INT0 interrupts, clearing pending flag, but likely setting the pending INTF0 on from multiple falling edges - and then your code continues to go into sleep mode with INT0 disabled so it cannot wake from sleep.

Just adding a reference for the accuracy of the internal RC osc: ATMega328P is indeed 10% factory, 1% with user calibration ATmega source, with the -PB part it is 2% factory, 1% with user calibration.

So, how should I put the atmega328p to sleep so that this doesn't happen?

@ErikVincent That's not what you originally asked, and it really depends on your clock source like I explained so I don't know what tradeoffs you want to make. First step, use the level sensitive mode for INT0 to wake up, second step is to clear pending INT0 flag before re-enabling INT0 interrupts so previously seen edges don't wake it up when you try to go to sleep. You could use some other lighter sleep mode which does not turn off clocks or allows edge interrupt detection or allows UART reception, but with crystal it can't start up fast enough to see first few bytes.

@Justme sorry for sounding like a newbie, but how/where do I use the level sensitive mode for the INT0 to wake up and is clearing the pending INT0 flag just a cli() function call with a later sei() function call later? Also, I am using a 16MHz crystal.

@ErikVincent The data sheet explains these. Also your comment says on one line that the INT0 is set as edge sensitive so please review that register. And near the INT0 mask there is INT0 pending flag as explained in the data sheet how to clear it. It's in the section that explains how to configure and use the EXTI interrupts.

@Justme, this still isn't making sense. When running, it goes to sleep. I send a character down it's RX line, and it wakes up. If it was only one character, it wakes up, blinks an LED and then goes back to sleep again. And it continues to work. It's only if a second or more character is pressed while it's in it's awake state that after that awake state it goes to sleep, it's stuck in sleep. From what you are saying, it should never wake up, even if only the one character is pressed, which is not true.

@ErikVincent I believe I explained the difference why it wakes on first time after sleep (interrupt was not pending) and why it does not wake the second time (pending interrupt disables further interrupts before going to sleep with interrupts disabled). For example, letter 'U' has a bit pattern of 5 falling and 5 rising edges. It is not a single edge and AVR interrupts get pending from each falling edge.

@Justme, if I press U once, it wakes, blinks, then goes to sleep. If I press U once again, it wakes, blinks, then goes to sleep. If I press U once again, it continues to work. If I press U and then U a second time within a second or so, it wakes, blinks, then goes to sleep and never wakes up. I would have thought the first, second, or third press of U with its 10 falling and rising edges should have froze the micro, but they don't. So is 20 falling and rising edges of pressing U twice in a row the number needed that crashes it?

@ErikVincent That is explained by the MCU taking a long time to start up and run the interrupt which means all edges of 'U' byte have happened when MCU runs the EXTI0 code which automatically clears the pending flag so there are no IRQs pending when LED is turned on. Notice your LED blinking has a total of 1 second delay, so if you send any byte during that time, you get a pending interrupt, which then causes a new EXTI0 IRQ to run when your sleep code enables interrupts an the IRQ disables them so sleep is entered interrupts disabled and it can't wake. The MCU does what the code tells it.


The MCU does what the code tells it.  | Computers tend to do what its told, and not what we want them to do. Annoying! /s

